# Jacobi Forms, Monstrous Moonshine, Hauptmodules: Relation between Specialization of q-Expansion

Tags: modular-forms, elliptic-modular-form

I have a weak jacobi form: $\phi(\tau,z)$ of weight $0$ and index $M=3$.

We know it has a "q-expansion":

$$\phi(\tau,z)=\sum_{n\geq 0,~l}c(n,l)q^ny^l$$

where $q=e^{2\pi i \tau}$ and $y=e^{2\pi i z}$.

I furthermore know its q-expansion for some special values of the variables:

\begin{align}\label{eq1}\phi(\tau,0)=C,~C\in\mathbb{R} \text{ (q-independent)}\tag{1}\end{align}

and:

\begin{align}\label{eq2}e^{2\pi i \tau}\phi(2\tau,\tau+\frac{1}{2})=q^2\phi(q^2,-q)=1-20q-62q^2-216q^3-641q^4-1636q^5-...\tag{2}\end{align}

Here the coefficients on the R.H.S. are given by the absolute value of those appearing in the  Mackay-Thompson series for conjugacy class $4C$ of the Monster group. It also turns out (via moonshine) that these are the coefficients of the q-expansion for the Hauptmodul of $\Gamma_0(4)$.

My question is the following: Can I say something about the q-expansion of

$$q^M\phi(\tau,\tau+\frac{1}{2})=\phi(\tau,\frac{1}{2})$$

(The equality comes from the "elliptic" transformation law for Jacobi forms.)

In fact I know that the above (viewed as a function of $\tau$) is a modular form of weight $0$ for the congruence subgroup $\Gamma_0(4)$.

### Attempts:

Numerics seems to indicate that the coefficients I am looking for are given by differences of those for Mackay-Thompson series $4A$ and $4C$ or by those of the q-expansion of $\frac{256}{T_{4C}(q)}$ where $T_{4C}$ the Mackay- Thompson series of type $4C$.

I know I have been quite vague on the specific definition of the series. I am only asking about some general direction to look at, my thoughts were:

- Specific properties of Jacobi forms allowing to relate different expansions.
- Relations between different Mackay-Thompson series ("replication identities" are mentioned in the sources but I don't understand this well-enough to decide if it might be relevant).
- Exploiting the fact that the function whose q-expansion whe want to constrain is a weight $0$ modular form for $\Gamma_0(4)$.

The last one seems the most promising, since we then know it can be expressed as a rational function of the Hauptmodule (related to $T_{4C}$). I am just looking for some hints about how to nail down which precise rational function. Maybe eq. \ref{eq1} and eq. \ref{eq2} can help.

### Sources:

T.Gannon: "Moonshine beyond the Monster", CUP.

[J. H. Conway, S. P. Norton: "Monstrous Moonshine"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.103.3704&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

[R.Borcherds: "Monstrous Moonshine and monstrous Lie Superalgebras"](https://math.berkeley.edu/~reb/papers/monster/monster.pdf).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should ask it on mathoverflow.net